# List of targets supported by binutils

Tags: binutils

I am following a website ( http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler ) to learn how to cross compile some code for different architectures. So, the first step is to download and compile Binutils for a specific target.

The site say to assign the varible TARGET with i686-elf because then the binutils will be able to handle code in the format specified by $TARGET.

```
export PREFIX="$HOME/opt/cross"
export TARGET=i686-elf
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"
```

So, my question is that

Can i get a list of targets that is supported by Binutils?

If the variable TARGET can contain anything or must be something that is supported by Binutils i.e would there be an error during compiling the source code of binutils, if the TARGET is something that binutils doesnt understand?

Answer (score 5):

Never saw an answer for this question, so I'll give it the ol college attempt for those coming from various search engines. If one downloads or clones binutils from sourceware

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
```

And then reads this explanation of binutils

```
https://sourceware.org/binutils/binutils-porting-guide.txt
```

You will find the answer.

---

**TL;DR**

Read the contents of **config.bfd** within the **bfd** directory

---

All the supported **targets** are listed within

```
cd /path/to/git/clone/of/binutils/bfd
```

**Notice** the files with **elf32-[SOME_NAME].c** and **elf64-[SOME_NAME].c** in the above mentioned directory, those are your supported **targets**.

**Ex**

```
elf32-cr16.c
```

would translate to,

```
--target=cr16-elf
```

Answer (score 0):

I just cloned binutils and found `gdb/README` has the most useful hint ([link](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/README;h=763089bb02d7b2bf2d437862961b50ce700d7c8b;hb=HEAD#l320)):

> The `configure' script accompanying GDB does not provide any query facility to list all supported host and target names or aliases.` configure' calls the Bourne shell script `config.sub' to map
> abbreviations to full names; you can read the script, if you wish, or
> you can use it to test your guesses on abbreviations--for example:

Now good luck crafting your triplet.